# Is it possible to find the Group ID or Name of logged-in user in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

Is it possible to find the Group/Grouping ID of logged-in user in Moodle 1.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Moodle Course there are three different Groups. I needed the ability to dynamically change the a href of a link on a webpage resource based on a User's Group Enrollment Key. This is what I did:

---

```
<div class="enrolment-key" style="display:none;">
<?php
    // Grab current User's group from Database By ID
    $sqlGROUPMEMBERS = "SELECT * FROM mdl_groups_members WHERE userid='$USER->id'";

    // Put Query in new Varible
    $resultGROUPMEMBERS = mysql_query($sqlGROUPMEMBERS);

    // While $row = group id of user
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultGROUPMEMBERS)){
        $groupID = $row["groupid"];
    }

    // Grab Enrolment Key by the Group ID
    $sqlGROUP = "SELECT * FROM mdl_groups WHERE id=$groupID";

    // Put Query in new Varible
    $resultENROLMENTKEY = mysql_query($sqlGROUP);

    // While $row = group enrolment key for that user
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultENROLMENTKEY)){
        echo $row["enrolmentkey"];
    }
?>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var baseURL = "https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/";
var endURL = $('.enrolment-key').html();

$(".survey-link").attr("href", baseURL + endURL);
 });
 </script>
<a class="survey-link">Link</a>
```

There probably is a better way to do this, but its fine for a Noob like me.